# call index action of I ndex controller from default file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am developing website in Magento. I am able to load localhost/index.php/hello.

But Now i want that when i load localhost/index.php it should automatically load localhost/index.php/hello.

I tried to search but haven't found any answers related to this.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set it from backend if you want to set home page for your custom action

just go to

**System -> Configuration -> Under general tab At Web**

Click on **Web** and go to **default pages tab**

change FAQ instead of your custom one.

[image]

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: @BSThakrar,glad to help you. pls vote up so someone can trust our thread and utilize in future needs.